# Problema Realm boolean y mysql

Tags: android, realm, booleano

Estoy aprendiendo android y he creado una app que gestiona lotes. Uso Realm para la persisténcia de datos y los recupero a través de retrofit de una tabla Mysql. Cuando recupero los datos boolean de la tabla Lote siempre me aparecen como false aunque en la tabla mysql tenga valores diferentes a 0. El problema entiendo que puede ser que el modelo Lote de Realm espera un valor true/false y encuentra un valor 0/1. Puede ser este el error? Como puedo solventarlo? Habia pensado en canviar los campos a String, pero si es posible me gustaria mantener el campo como boolean.

Aquí el código:

```
   public class Lote extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private String Lote;
private String Producto;
private int Quantidad;
private boolean Activado;
private boolean Defecto;
private int Syncro;

@Required
private Date datalote;

public Lote(){}

public Lote(String lote, String producto, int quantidad, boolean activado, boolean defecto, int syncro)
{
    this.id = MyApplication.LoteID.incrementAndGet();
    Lote = lote;
    Producto = producto;
    Quantidad = quantidad;
    Activado = activado;
    Defecto = defecto;
    Syncro = syncro;
    this.datalote = new Date();
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getLote() {
    return Lote;
}

public void setLote(String lote) {
    Lote = lote;
}

public String getProducto() {
    return Producto;
}

public void setProducto(String producto) { Producto = producto; }

public int getQuantidad() {
    return Quantidad;
}

public void setQuantidad(int quantidad) {
    Quantidad = quantidad;
}

public boolean getActivado() {return  Activado; }

public void setActivado(boolean activado) { Activado = activado; }

public boolean getDefecto() {return Defecto; }

public void setDefecto(boolean defecto) {Defecto = defecto; }

public  int getSyncro() {return Syncro; }

public void setSyncro(int syncro) { Syncro = syncro; }

public Date getDataLote() { return datalote; }
```

El codigo para recibir datos de la tabla mysql:

```
loteCall.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Lote>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<Lote>> call, Response<ArrayList<Lote>> response) {
            ArrayList<Lote> lotesel = response.body();
            for(Lote item : lotesel) {
                String nomlote = item.getLote();
                String producto = item.getProducto();
                int quantidad = item.getQuantidad();
                boolean activado = item.getActivado();
                boolean defecto= item.getDefecto();
                int syncro = item.getSyncro();
                Date date = item.getDataLote();
                realm.beginTransaction();
                Lote lote = new Lote(nomlote, producto, quantidad, activado, defecto, syncro);
                realm.copyToRealm(lote);
                realm.commitTransaction();
                txtLotes.setTextColor(txtLotes.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.facturapagada));
                txtLotes.setText(getString(R.string.txt_dblotesok));
            }
        }
```

Comment: comprueba la petición del servidor si realmente los boleanos se reciben bien, ya que por defecto el valor de los boleanos es false

Comment: Los datos que muestra el servidor són correctos. He probado con dar un valor 1, 2, 5... diferentes de 0 pero todos me devuelve false. El Json que responde el servidor és:  [{"id":"1","Lote":"Lote Defecto","Producto":"Defecto","Quantidad":"0","Activado":"5","Defecto":"5","Syncro":"0","Date":"2018-02-09"}, {"id":"2","Lote":"Lote Prueba","Producto":"Alcachofas","Quantidad":"200","Activado":"0","Defecto":"0","Syncro":"0","Date":"2018-02-08"}] Sigo investigando... Gracias pero! ;)

Comment: Puede ser que como lo devuelves entre doble comillas lo obtiene como cadena, mira de hacer que los Boleanos devuelve `{ "sale":true }` es decir el true y false que no estén en comillas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he encontrado una solucion. He modificado el tipo de dato de la tabla mysql por varchar y he dado valores de true y false. Me sirvio mucho la aportacion que me hiciste de quitar las comillas pero la clase de Realm no asumia 1/0 como true/false y saltaba un error al entender que un int no podia ser un boolean.

Es una solucion un poco de pega pero tengo que acabar la app y no he encontrado otra opción. Aunque tambien podria mantener la tabla mysql con datos boolean y al pasar a json con php transformar los valores a true/false.

La verdad no sé qual de las dos opciones es más limpia. Espero que a otras personas les sirva.

Saludos!